# I want to find that whether particular sub graph is present in a graph in ruby

Tags: ruby

By using the RGL library in ruby, how to find presence of a sub graph in a graph.

Comment: Could you give me the definition of the graph and sub-graph? and how does it look like? what type of graph is it?

Comment: For example, In a DirectedGrpah { <1,2>, <1,3>, <3,4>, <3,5>, <4,6>, <6,5>, <5,7>, <7,8>, <8,9>, <9,7> }, i need to check this graph  (portion of graph) { <5,7>, <7,8>, <8,9>, <9,7> } present in the previous graph......

Comment: I have given a code,hope it helps:)

Comment: Is the solution OK with you?

Comment: What options have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here [`set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-proper_subset-3F)

*Here is a hints code:*

```
p RUBY_VERSION
require 'set'


arr = [ [1,2], [1,3], [3,4], [3,5], [4,6], [6,5], [5,7],[7,8]]
arr1 = [[1,3],[3,4]]
arr2 = [[10,11],[4,5]]
dirgraph = Set.new()
subgraph = Set.new()
subgraph1 = Set.new()

arr.each{|x|
dirgraph.add(x)
}

p dirgraph

arr1.each{|x|
subgraph.add(x)
}

p subgraph

arr2.each{|x|
subgraph1.add(x)
}

p subgraph1

p subgraph.subset?(dirgraph)
p subgraph1.subset?(dirgraph)
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
#<Set: {[1, 2], [1, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [6, 5], [5, 7], [7, 8]}>
#<Set: {[1, 3], [3,4]}>
#<Set: {[10, 11], [4, 5]}>
true
false
```